# Angularjs custom directive for select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, combobox

I am creating a custom directive named "combo". i pass to it the options from the main controller, however i need to get the value selected from the parent controller.

The scenario:

> Rendering:

I have an array called **$scope.fields** which contains the different types of controls to be presented to the user.  i am looping in these array to check draw a text input or combo.

> Binding

the  **$scope.fieldValues** will synchronize that values input from the user.
The text input is changing the value in **fieldValues[$index].value**. So i can get the final values from the fieldValues by specifying the relative index.

> The Problem

How can i make the combo binded to its associated **fieldValues[$index].value**.
or how can i get the selected item for any combo from the parent controller.

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
   angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.fields = [{ name: 'customers', type: 'combo' }, { name: 'Name', type: 'text' }, { name: 'country', type: 'combo' }]
    $scope.fieldValues = [{ value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }];
    $scope.myItems = ['Item 1', 'Item 2'];
    $scope.itemId = 1;


    $scope.log = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.fieldValues.length; i++) {
            if (!angular.isUndefined($scope.fieldValues[i].value))
                console.log($scope.fieldValues[i].value);
        }

    }
})
 
 
.directive('combo', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<div class="input-group"> <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="changeEvent()" >' +
                    '<option ng-value="model" ng-repeat="model in items">{{model}}</option></select>' +
                    ' {{selectedItem}} </div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            defaultItem: '=',
            changeEvent: '&'
          
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {

        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.selectedItem = scope.items[scope.defaultItem];
            scope.changeEvent = function () {
                //console.log("changed");
                console.log(scope.selectedItem);
            }
        }
    };
});

    </script>
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
        <div ng-if="field.type == 'combo'">
            <strong>{{field.name}}</strong>
            <div combo items="myItems" default-item="itemId"></div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="field.type == 'text'">
            <strong>{{field.name}}</strong>
            <input type="text" ng-model="fieldValues[$index].value" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="log" ng-click="log()" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working `plunker` with what you want: http://plnkr.co/edit/TEh9kauHCVfCPSw552c9?p=preview

The thing is that you are using isolated scope of directives, so you should pass `fieldValues[$index].value` to it.

Take a look at it!

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this but with ng-options instead of ng-repeat?